# ACPI ERROR: No pointer back to namespace node in package ... troubleshoot it?

Tags: startup, acpi

I am getting the following errors and my Ubuntu won't start up.

[image: Ubuntu stuck and giving errors]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, as that will help in troubleshooting your issue. Also, what is the context of your issue (was this the result of a new install, an update/upgrade, new hardware, etc.)? Thanks